# Accessing the radio button value

Tags: javascript

Html Code: -

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="1" onclick="validate()"> For Yourself</input> </p></br>
    <p>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="2" onclick="validate()"> For Users</input>
    </p>
```

And JavaScript Code : -

```
function validate()
    {
        var btn_value=document.getElementById("radio").value;
        if(btn_value==true)
        {
            alert(btn_value);
        }

    }
```

Now, whenever I am trying to print the value of radio button. It is always printing value as 1.

So, Now I don't understand what exactly am I missing here...

Thanx in advance for your help.

Comment: You can only have one element with a specific ID. `document.getElementById` will usually get the first one in document order although this behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements `ID` should be unique. I modified your HTML and JS part and check below

Try this

**HTML**

```
<p>
     <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="1" onclick="validate(this)"> For Yourself</input> </p></br>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="2" onclick="validate(this)"> For Users</input>
</p>
```

**JavaScrpit**

```
function validate(obj)
    {
        var btn_value=obj.value;
        if(btn_value==true)
        {
            alert(btn_value);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all never use a DOMID twice in your html!
remove them.... only use dublicated names!

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" onclick="validate()"> For Yourself</input> </p></br>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" onclick="validate()"> For Users</input>
</p>
```

with the js check every element with the name attribute!

```
function validate() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("radio");
    for(var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++) {
        if(elements[n].checked === true) {
            alert(elements[n].value);
        }
    }
}
```

if you use your validate method ONLY in the onclick you can pass the domelement in the validate methode like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" onclick="validate(this)"> For Yourself</input> </p>
```

and your js:

```
function validate(domElement) {
     if(domElement.checked === true) {
            alert(elements[n].value);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="1" onclick="validate(this)"> For Yourself</input> </p></br>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="2" onclick="validate(this)"> For Users</input>
</p>​

function validate(ele)
{
    alert(ele.value);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

1. IDs MUST be unique, it's a mistake to give it the same id.
2. You can give the IDs a running number (- radio1,radio2 etc) and loop through them to check which one was selected.